# error while building 2d map

Tags: slam, navigation, odometry, mapping, base-link

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi
i am trying to build 2d map i go just part of the map and git in the axis error that say in rviz:
Transform
For frame [base_link]: No transform to fixed frame [map]. TF error: [Could not find a connection between 'map' and 'base_link' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.]
ithe odometery data  are publishing and the kinect work fine i don't know where the problem is
i will include all the information that can help:
i am using indigo
first i use this launch file

```
<param name="port" value="/dev/ttyACM0" />

<param name="baud" value="115200" />
```

```
<param name="publish_tf" value="true" />

<param name="publish_rate" value="10.0" />

<param name="linear_scale_positive" value="0.99" />

<param name="linear_scale_negative" value="0.99" />


<param name="angular_scale_positive" value="1.0" />


<param name="angular_scale_negative" value="1.0" />

<param name="angular_scale_accel" value="0.0" />

<param name="alpha" value="0.5" />

<param name="use_imu" value="true" />
```

and

```
<node name="teleop" pkg="teleop_twist_keyboard" type="teleop_twist_keyboard.py" output="screen" launch-prefix="xterm -e"/>

<node pkg="rviz" name="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find beginner_tutorials)/launch/rviz/slam.rviz"/>
```

and it must run good
base controller is running without any problem and  publish the odom data
the tf tree and rviz
[Screenshot from 2016-06-18 19:51:20.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14662687908962767.png)
[Screenshot from 2016-06-18 19:52:30.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/1466268808500082.png)

i hope this can help.

note: you can find base_controller in this package https://github.com/sungjik/my_personal_robotic_companion
I use it as a reference with some difference but the tf publish is the same . I am launch robot config and slam.launch from this package I hope this information will help.

note2: after adding this line befor launch

rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 map base_footprint 100
no error occure in rviz but still the axises don't move when the robot move i still don't know why this is the tree after adding this line
[image: image description]

it's make the map in the same place don't move  and the in the odom data
seq: 1839
stamp:
secs: 1466341747
nsecs: 223550043
frame_id: /odom
child_frame_id: /base_link
pose:
pose:
position:
x: 0.00107754043214
y: -0.000931717192192
z: 0.0
orientation:
x: 0.0
y: 0.0
z: -0.260476129843
w: 0.96548028762

when the position change no change in the position of the robot while building the map.

note3: i use this befor the launch and this make appropriate tf tree

rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 odom base_footprint 100

and this is the tree

[image: image description]

and here no problem occure in rviz the tree is good but still the axis not move correctley when i move it take a while to move and not in the same direction and when the robot is in the same place for a while it's move the axis move while the robot not moving
i know this is a different story but i hope u can help i got this msg some time
when i build the map

update frame 4753
update ld=0.3162 ad=2.30165
Laser Pose= -0.17 0.02 -0.00663924
m_count 26
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=6.9527e-310
lp:0.130364 0.118812 -2.30829
op:-0.17 0.02 -0.00663924
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.130364 0.118812 -2.30829
op:-0.17 0.02 -0.00663924
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4180.05
lp:0.130364 0.118812 -2.30829
op:-0.17 0.02 -0.00663924
Scan Matching Failed, using odometry. Likelihood=-4266.67
lp:0.130364 0.118812 -2.30829

note 4:
this is the odometery

geometry_msgs::TransformStamped t;

```
  t.header.frame_id = odom;
```

t.child_frame_id = base_link;

t.transform.translation.x = x_pos;

```
  t.transform.translation.y = y_pos;

  t.transform.translation.z = 0.0;

  t.transform.rotation = odom_quat;

  t.header.stamp = current_time;


  broadcaster.sendTransform(t);
```

i hope you can help me. and thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237430/error-while-building-2d-map/) by [ghaith](https://answers.ros.org/users/26984/ghaith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2016-06-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shantnu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26813/shantnu/) on 2016-06-18**:
Are you publishing map->odom transformation anywhere or is it there by default?

**Comment by [ghaith](https://answers.ros.org/users/26984/ghaith/) on 2016-06-18**:
i use the control base from this package https://github.com/sungjik/my_personal_robotic_companion
with some difference but still the method of publish tf is th same I hope this will help.

**Comment by [Shantnu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26813/shantnu/) on 2016-06-18**:
So basically some node name base_controller which belongs to beginner_tutorials pkg is publishing the tf for you? Is that correct?

**Comment by [Shantnu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26813/shantnu/) on 2016-06-18**:
Secondly, the problem is the missing connection between base_link and map frame. To set that up, try doing this in your terminal before launching your launch file:

rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 map base_footprint 100

**Comment by [Shantnu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26813/shantnu/) on 2016-06-18**:
it feels like the sequence of tf is wrong. It should be like map->odom-> base_footprint-> base_link. For you, it odom comes after base_footprint, which feels weird.

**Comment by [ghaith](https://answers.ros.org/users/26984/ghaith/) on 2016-06-19**:
this work but still the axises don't move when the robot move but in rviz no error occure  every thing work fine but the axises don't move i don't know why

**Comment by [ghaith](https://answers.ros.org/users/26984/ghaith/) on 2016-06-19**:
how i can solve this how i can make footprint child of odom and father of base linke
i think this will solve move problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK, so you have two problems here that I can see off the bat, and they are both related.

First, get rid of the static transform from map->base_footprint. Gmapping knows to update the map when that transform changes (either in translation or rotation) by a user specified amount. By using a static transform, that transform will never change and therefore the map will never update.

Second, looking at Screenshot from 2016-06-18 19:51:20.png, you can see that there is no transform between odom->base_footprint. You may have something publishing an nav_msgs/Odometry message, but there is nothing publishing the transform to the tf topic. I don't know what your odometry node looks like, but it seems to be missing the transform publisher. Take a look at lines 43-55 in the sample code of the odom [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom).

[EDIT]
Change the `t.child_frame_id = base_link;` to `t.child_frame_id = base_footprint;`. Frames can have multiple children but only a single parent. The way it is set up now, base_link is the child of both base_footprint and odom. As this isn't allowed it will latch onto the first parent to be published, in this case base_footprint.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2016-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ghaith](https://answers.ros.org/users/26984/ghaith/) on 2016-06-21**:
thanks for replay i update post and the odemtery is published in the same way

**Comment by [ghaith](https://answers.ros.org/users/26984/ghaith/) on 2016-06-21**:
this solution work great no problem but just small question now when the robot move just turn the axies is it in the odometery problem . the robot don't move forward but building the map without any problem but it turn around the same point

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-06-21**:
The map only rotates around the z axis, there is no translation? Can you give me a link to the node you are using?

**Comment by [ghaith](https://answers.ros.org/users/26984/ghaith/) on 2016-06-21**:
i am using the appropriately the same method in this package
https://github.com/sungjik/my_personal_robotic_companion
in the base controller node i don't know what the problem i am publish the imu from arduino this is all the defferince and i run robot confg launch and slam all the odom change

**Comment by [ghaith](https://answers.ros.org/users/26984/ghaith/) on 2016-06-21**:
when i move forward x and y change and it's positve if i move back ward x and y will be negative and if imove left x will be + and y - and so on so i don't know what is the reason every thing work fine and the robot move in the real world but not in the map in the map just rotate in the z axis

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-06-21**:
That sounds like the kinematics are wrong. What kind of robot is it? Omnidirectional, skid-steer, or ackerman?

**Comment by [ghaith](https://answers.ros.org/users/26984/ghaith/) on 2016-06-21**:
it's diff wheels robot

**Comment by [ghaith](https://answers.ros.org/users/26984/ghaith/) on 2016-06-21**:
if there any other way to set the kinematics plz give it to me any tutorial or example or even an issue it will be great and thanks for your help .

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-06-21**:
You'd have to look up the kinematic equations for a differential drive online and check the equations in the controller. Remember that ROS uses right hand rule: x+ forward, y+ left, z+ up

**Comment by [ghaith](https://answers.ros.org/users/26984/ghaith/) on 2016-06-21**:
thanks for your help

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-06-21**:
No problem